# how to remove header, transpose the data & combine two csv in a single file?

Tags: python, csv, transpose

I have two csv files in a folder which look like below:
File 1:

```
col1   col2       
1      2    
3       4
```

File 2:

```
col1 col2
5       6
7       8
```

I want to read the files from the folder, then remove the header name (col1,col2) and then change the rows to column and column to rows that means transpose it and merge those two files into a new csv file which would look as below:

```
1 3 5 7    
2 4 6 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.T` and `pandas.concat`:

Let's say your files or preferably csvs look like these:

```
files = ['csv1.csv', 'csv2.csv']

csv1
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
csv2
   col1  col2
0     5     6
1     7     8
```

Then with help of `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file).T for file in files], 1)

      0  1  0  1
col1  1  3  5  7
col2  2  4  6  8
```

Comment: u need to tell also how to read csv file from folder and make them dataframe . your solution is half solution of whole problem

Comment: Hey, I have 900 files to do this operation and I want to save it to a new csv file. How to do that?

Comment: @T.Mou Do you have a list of file paths?

Comment: @Chris all the files are in one folder. the files name are like "0_dcef_abcd_cdef", "1_dcef_cdef_abcd" and inside the files the columns look like the given one in the question. I want to create a new csv file where the columns will look like:
col1 col2     col3     col4       col5    col6
0      dcef    abcd     cdef       1,3     2,4
1      dcef    cdef       abcd     5,7     6,8